# How to scrape an email adress on a sub page with web scraper?

Tags: database, email, web-scraping, plugins, multiple-select

I have a data base on which I can filter some criterias.
On the main page of my research I have all the profiles that match my research.
But if I want to have their email adresses, I have to click on each profile to access their profile page with where I can find this info.
I have installed web scraper but I do not know if it can go to a sub page to scrape the info I want.
Does someone know if it is possible with Web scraper or another tool ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: You say you "installed a web scraper". Did you install a library for web scraping, or did you install a web scraping program? If it is the latter, this question might not belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I meant that I downloaded the chrome extension that I can use by going to "more tools" in the tool bar. Then I go to "development tools" so a box appear at the bottom of the page. I have to select "web scraper" and then choose "create a new sitemap". After it where I struggle because I do not know how I can make it understand to navigate through each profile to get the email address. Have you already use the tool web scraper or another one that could do this ?